# How do I get this navbar to shrink with the size of the page?

Tags: css

Is there a way to get this navbar to shrink within the size of the page? On full desktop screen, all the navbars show correctly, yet when I shrink the page, the navbar stays the same size and goes outside of the parameters.

in this image, on the bottom where it says "acce." it is supposed to show "accessories", yet when i shrink the screen size the navbar gets cut off.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to make a reproducible example so that anyone can debug the code.

Comment: Use property unit of measurements as a percentage of viewport `vh`, `vw` on the parent nav.